# In regards to delegation, what happens if recursion is not allowed by the parent name server?

Tags: dns, delegation

For example, if I resolved a DNS request for a host device in the child domain, would the request remain successful with recursion not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Er, maybe?

All DNS lookups basically work by recursing down from the root to the servers that have the authoritative information. The only question is who actually does the work. A name server with recursion activated says "Yeah, sure, I'll do that for you, ask me anything". A name server with recursion turned off says "Nope, I'll only answer questions I'm authoritative for, do your own recursion, you lazy bum".

Most devices don't do their own recursion. Instead, they know the address of a friendly name server who'll do it for them. If your name server is that kind of name server, and you disallow recursion, things are going to suck for the devices who relied on it doing it for them.

If your name server is providing authoritative information for some domain, it's very strongly recommended that it have recursion turned off. If it's currently doing both, stop that and split the different tasks up on two different server installations.